# weblogic 12c org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl

Tags: java, swagger, jax-rs, weblogic, jersey-2.0

i've an already structured Application with RESTful APIs that are needed to be documented with swagger (version 1.5.24).

after implementing it, when trying to deploy on **Weblogic 12.2.1.2.0** i receive this error as the application starts:

```
    <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "mypackage.test.RestContainer" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "test.war".
A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=ServiceLocator,parent=JaxbAutoDiscoverable,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1751700306)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:75)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:941)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:980)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1055)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1046)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureAutoDiscoverableProviders(CommonConfig.java:608)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureAutoDiscoverableProviders(ResourceConfig.java:811)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:447)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:343)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:294)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:99)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:93)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:69)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:36)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:666)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:612)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:2054)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:2031)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1920)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3091)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1823)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:882)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:750)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:260)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:627)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:347)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:901)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1456)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:456)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused By: org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=ServiceLocator,parent=JaxbAutoDiscoverable,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1751700306)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:75)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:941)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:980)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1055)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1046)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureAutoDiscoverableProviders(CommonConfig.java:608)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureAutoDiscoverableProviders(ResourceConfig.java:811)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:447)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:343)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:294)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:99)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:93)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:69)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:36)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:666)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:612)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:2054)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:2031)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1920)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3091)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1823)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:882)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:750)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:260)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:627)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:347)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:901)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1456)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:456)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

This is my RestContainer.java:

```
import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;
import mypackage.test.data.Costanti;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;  
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;  

@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class RestContainer extends Application {  

    
    public RestContainer() {
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
        beanConfig.setTitle("MyAppTest");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[] {
                "http", "https"
        });
        beanConfig
        .setResourcePackage("mypackage.test.services");
        beanConfig.setHost(Costanti.ENV_DOMAIN_URL);
        beanConfig.setBasePath("rest");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
        
    }    


    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        // set your resources here
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        //api classes
        resources.add(mypackage.test.services.BuildaccessResource.class);
        resources.add(mypackage.test.services.DevicesResource.class);  
        resources.add(mypackage.test.services.DispositiviResource.class);
        resources.add(mypackage.test.services.LoginService.class);
        resources.add(mypackage.test.services.PersonaResource.class);
        resources.add(mypackage.test.services.RecoverQueueResource.class);
        resources.add(mypackage.test.services.RegioniResource.class);
        resources.add(mypackage.test.services.ReportisticaService.class);
        resources.add(mypackage.test.services.SediResource.class);
        resources.add(mypackage.test.services.ServiziResource.class);
        resources.add(mypackage.test.services.SistemiResource.class);
        resources.add(mypackage.test.services.StatisticResource.class);
        
        resources.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
        resources.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);
        //features

        
        return resources;
    }    
}
```

**Here my actual pom.xml dependencies:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-property-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- logs -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
       <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
       <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JWT -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- PDF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.13</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
        <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>9.20</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- SWAGGER -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.24</version>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

**And this is my weblogic.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.6/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <context-root>/appTest</context-root>
    <session-descriptor>
         <cookie-name>JSESSIONID_API</cookie-name>
    </session-descriptor>
    <container-descriptor> 
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

I've followed the guide [Swagger Core Jersey 2.X Project Setup 1.5](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5) Using a custom Application subclass method

Looking at the error is says something about injection but i do not execute nothing of that kind in the application.
I really miss where the error could be and how to get rid of it.

Unfortunately i came from positive tests made on Jboss that didn't show any error at launch. So is there is a module ( or more modules ) that are probably missing?
or is it a code issue?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: My guess is the Swagger version you are using pulls in a Jersey version that is incompatible with the Jersey version already included in WebLogic. I would try to exclude all the Jersey dependencies from Swagger, since WebLogic already has them. If that doesn't work, then find out what version of Jersey, your WebLogic uses, then try to use the Swagger version that pulls in a compatible/similar version. DI was changed in Jersey 2.26, so if one uses below and one uses above, this could cause your error.

Comment: Thanks man, that helped me to reach the solution, i had to modify some pom dependencies too and the weblogic.xml and now it seems working pretty well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread Solved thanks to the suggestion of [Paul Samsotha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/paul-samsotha)

I've excluded all jersey dependencies of swagger:

```
<!-- SWAGGER -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.24</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Then for Hibernate i had to exclude jakarta-validation and put javax-validator:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then i've modified the weblogic.xml in this manner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.6/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <context-root>/appTest</context-root>
    <session-descriptor>
         <cookie-name>JSESSIONID_API</cookie-name>
    </session-descriptor>
    <container-descriptor> 
         <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes> 
        <!-- <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes -->
        
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>org.apache.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.hibernate.validator.*</package-name> 
            <package-name>org.jboss.logging.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javax.validation.*</package-name>
            <package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</package-name>
            <package-name>com.google.common.*</package-name>
            <package-name>com.thetransactioncompany.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Thanks for the help!